# Copy and Paste Issue

Tags: excel, vba

This code works two or three times, and then I get a "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed" error. I know I get that error when nothing is copied, but considering it's copied right above, I don't understand why it's not working.

When I debug and watch it step by step, it loops back to the beginning after the Paste line, rather than running through the end of the Sub.

```
Sub AddRows()
   Range("A11").End(xlDown).EntireRow.Copy
   Range("A11").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Any ideas?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Kindly 'close' the questions by marking correct answers. This is what people here like when helping others. It will help ppl with same problem to identify the correct solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code : The copy and paste operation can be combined in 1 line.
Below code copies the range from cell `A11` till the last cell which has the data and paste the data in very next cell below.

```
 Sub AddRows()


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A11:A" & lastRow)

    ' Next row
    rng.Copy Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)

    'if you want data to be pasted to Column B use below
    'rng.Copy rng.Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```